# how to create an incident in serviceNow from salesforce(Case)?

Tags: apex, integration, case, callout, servicenow

I'm trying to integrate salesforce and serviceNow. If I create a new case in salesforce, that should be saved as incident in serviceNow.

Here I developed some code but I'm stuck at mapping the salesforce case fields with serviveNow incident fieds.

```
Public with sharing class OutboundMsg {


    public static void servicenowPost(){  

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req =  new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

         String username = 'admin';
         String password = '$Test12345';

        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
        EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);



        req.setEndpoint('https://dev23577.service-now.com/');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 



        //Id caseId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
      //  Case c = new Case(subject='',status='new',origin='web');
        //insert c;
       // req.setBody('c');

       // Create a new http object to send the request object
       // A response object is generated as a result of the request  


        res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());


   }
}
```

How can I establish the mapping between salesforce and serviceNow?

Answer (score 3):

The ServiceNow API accepts json/xml you'll have to change your content-type to application/json and create the mappings in a json format. You can use the [JSON Generator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm) to build your request.

Here's a quick example:

Apex Class

```
@future
public static void servicenowPost(Case incidentCase){  

Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req =  new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

String username = 'admin';
String password = '$Test12345';

Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

req.setEndpoint('https://dev23577.service-now.com/');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
gen.writeStartObject();

//you can add as many mappings as you want
gen.writeStringField('servicenowField', incidentCase.field);
gen.writeEndObject();

//you can now use String pretty as your body
String pretty = gen.getAsString();

req.setBody(pretty);
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

system.debug(res.getBody());
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger servicenow on Case (after insert){
for(Case c : Trigger.New){                                                  
  nameofyourcalloutclass.servicenowPost(c);                                                                          
  }
}
```

Comment: that's fine but guide me how to map the saerviceNow incident fields with salesforce case fields.

Comment: @sushanth are you going to use a trigger or a visualforce page to create the incident in servicenow?

Comment: yes though trigger i'm going to create incident flow

Comment: @sushanth I've updated the answer post above with an example

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample curl to post incident in ServiceNow

```
curl "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident" \
--request POST \
--header "Accept:application/json"\
--header "Content-Type:application/json" \
--data "{'short_description':'Unable to connect to office wifi','assignment_group':'287ebd7da9fe198100f92cc8d1d2154e','urgency':'2','impact':'2'}" \
--user 'username':'password'
```

complete reference: https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=madrid&id=r_TableAPI-POST